# About symmetric distributions

Tags: self-study, distributions, independence, bivariate, symmetry

Homework problem:
if $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables, where $Y$ is symmetric about 0, define $U = X + Y , V = X- Y$. Then say whether $U$ and $V$ have the same distribution or not.

This is what I know about symmetric distributions:
the distribution of rv X is symmetric about a iff  F(a-X ) = 1- F(a+X)
=> f(a-x) = f (a+x), 
where F IS CDF and f is pdf 
but I can't think how to use this theory to reach the solution

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Hint: define $Z$ as $-Y$. Then, $Z$ and $X$ are also independent random variables, and since $Y$ has a symmetric distribution, then so does $Z$ have the _very same_ symmetric distriibution. So $(X,Y)$ and $(X,Z) = (X,-Y)$ have the same _joint_ distribution.......